# Apple StoreKit - Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, storekit

I need to implement Apple StoreKit to process subscriptions in my APP, ¿how can I make this?

I'm triying install Ionic and implement after RevenueCat ([Docs.](https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/getting-started/installation/ionic)) but I have problems with packages:

```
The package @ionic/angular@6.7.5 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.1.2
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@12.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"^12.0.0" from @angular/flex-layout@12.0.0-beta.34
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/flex-layout
npm ERR!       @angular/flex-layout@"12.0.0-beta.34" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@">=10.0.0-0" from @ctrl/ngx-rightclick@4.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ctrl/ngx-rightclick
npm ERR!       @ctrl/ngx-rightclick@"4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=12.0.0" from @angular/flex-layout@12.0.0-beta.34
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout
npm ERR!     @angular/flex-layout@"12.0.0-beta.34" from the root project
npm ERR!   11 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^11.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"9.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^11.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"9.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/davgracia/.npm/_logs/2024-03-12T11_34_12_786Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/davgracia/.npm/_logs/2024-03-12T11_34_12_786Z-debug-0.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
```

How can resolve this?

Comment: The error message says you're trying to install `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` version `9.1.2` (which requires `@angular/common` version `^11.0.0`) into a project using `@angular/common` version `13.1.0`. Looking at [the dependencies section of the `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap?activeTab=readme#dependencies), we see that you want version `11.x.x` for Bootstrap 4 or version `12.x.x` for Bootstrap 5 if you're using `@angular` version `^13.0.0`. You'll need to edit your `package.json` file and run `npm i` again.

Comment: Your title is misleading. you say Apple StoreKit but in your error your showing install  @ionic/angular@6.7.5..... this question is a mess... fix this..